Canon EDSDK won't send me any OnLiveViewUpdated after few use without restarting my Camera
i have an app (.NET 8.0, WPF) that display the liveview of the camera so the people can see themsefl before and during the recording of a small video.
It work perfectly fine one time but if i use it too much or if i switch to fast between liveview on/off the liveView updated won't send me anything, the live view is started, the camera just don't send any image, if i record the camera still work fine and save the film.
I try to find if anything was appening in the EDSKK of canon but no error is throw anywhere and i can't find anything that goes wrong
private void CamSession_OnLiveViewUpdated(Camera sender, Stream img)
{
    try
    {
        if (camSession.mainCamera.IsLiveViewOn)
        {
            using (System.Drawing.Bitmap image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(img)))
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                ms.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.BeginInit();

                bi.StreamSource = ms;
                bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bi.EndInit();
                bi.Freeze();

                LVCanvas.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
                {
                    LVCanvas.Background = new ImageBrush(bi);
                }));

                ms.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        Debug.WriteLine("ERROR");
    }
}

Edit :
just found out i have those errors as well:

'EOSDigital.API.SDKException' SEVERE ERROR : NOT_SUPPORTED
'System.PlatformNotSupportedException'

Edit 2 :
public PriseVideo(Utilisateur inv)

{
InitializeComponent();
camSession = new CameraSession(true);
camSession.OnLiveViewUpdated += CamSession_OnLiveViewUpdated;
camSession.startLV();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(3 * 1000))
.ContinueWith((t) =>
{
    if (!camSession.mainCamera.IsLiveViewOn)
    {
        camSession.mainCamera.Dispose();
        camSession.mainCamera = null;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(3 * 1000))
        .ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
               camSession = new CameraSession(true);
               camSession.OnLiveViewUpdated += CamSession_OnLiveViewUpdated;
               camSession.startLV();
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

}
i just reload all if nothing is shown after few secondes, not the best way to do it but it seem to work

Why are you creating a System.Drawing.Bitmap instead of directly decoding a BitmapImage from the Stream? I.e. bi.StreamSource = img;

It is also not necessary to create a new ImageBrush each time. You could as well assign the ImageSource property of an already existing ImageBrush.

Have you tried to replace the code from the event handler, with some Debug.WriteLine(...) to check if it make any difference about receiving the event after too many on/offs?

the event handler is just not called anymore when to many on/off
